# How to implement page transitions within a bottom sheet in .NET MAUI?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, maui, bottom-sheet

I'm working on a .NET MAUI application where I need to implement page transitions within a bottom sheet. My goal is to achieve this without creating a new bottom sheet for each page transition. Is there a recommended approach for achieving this, such as using ContentView or any other best practices?

Comment: You can custom the contentview as the bottom sheet for the contentpage.